# Forcing a game to not take "real local IP" into account but only recognize virtual local IP assigned by VPN server

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, tcp, gaming

We are two friends who want to play Heroes of Might and Magic 2, 3 or 5 together in online multiplayer mode over internet using a TCP/IP connection.

As we are not happy with third party solutions like Tunngle and Gameranger, we decided to use our VPN server for this purpose.

We both can connect to VPN server and obtain virtual local IP addresses through VPN server. I use L2TP connection and he uses OpenVPN connection. It is a Softether VPN server so it supports both. There is no problem with our VPN connection.

However Heroes of Might and Magic 3 does not recognize the IP assigned by VPN server, instead it detects our real local IP address from our ethernet devices.

This same problem occurred to me while I am using a Windows (8.1) for this purpose, and also to my friend, who runs the game via Wine.

My question is, how can we prevent this game to take our real local IP into account and recognize only our virtual local IP addresses?

Comment: "our real local IP address from our ethernet devices." this does not make sense.  This would be only the case if the game only supports local multiplayer.  "take our real local IP" this again does not make sense, the VPN address your being assigned, isn't a local lan ip address.

Comment: When I use `ipconfig` command I can see both local IP addresses. Real one is from ethernet device, virtual one is from VPN. So I guess this game is written to focus into the real one and ignore any other. By the way this game supports both local multiplayer and online multiplayer.

Comment: You might want to try Hamachi.  It works with games with basic networking functionality

Comment: I have tried this on Windows XP SP3 under Virtualbox running as a guest on a Mac. Same result. Hamachi is discontinued as far as I know. We want to make a VPN connection and use it crossplatform (Mac and Linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have finally solved this issue after days passed by looking for solution, researching and trying our alternatives. Finally it works now. I will give details about our working configuration. Actually it is simple.

We both use official OpenVPN clients to connect to VPN. This is necessary. Windows let you connect directly to VPN without using third party software, but don't use that for this purpose. Use OpenVPN clients.

Games and OpenVPN clients run on Windows XP SP3 as guest OS in VirtualBox. Host computers' OS are Mac OS X 10.9 and Arch Linux.

Arch Linux uses default network settings in VirtualBox. However Mac's Virtualbox needed to be  configured: PCnet-FAST III adapter should be selected in NAT mode to let the guest OS connect to the internet.

Now we can play these games without using any third party software. It is really great. I know many people are looking for a way to have a smooth gaming experience over internet with old games. Maybe this can be an alternative solution for gamers like us.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post, but here is what we do:

1. Go to list of network adapters
2. Disable every adapter instead of the virtual one
3. Open the game and go into the multiplayer lobby, the furthers you can go without actually joining the game
4. Enable your real internet adapter (and the others you disabled if you need them)

This should force the game to use the virtual ip/adapter.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work. I'm using wireguard and the game will show it's designated tunnel IP at on top of the lobby list but it never translates to anything useful. As soon as you enable the normal adapter, the game seems to switch to it. I'm trying my hardest here to figure out how to give the tunnel priority over the local internet.